# With node.js, can I make some functions available without import, for a DSL?

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules, javascript-import

I'm trying to use Javascript and Node.js to create a DSL for a certain application. I'd like my files have certain predefined functions available, without having to import them.

Example file: `dsl_script.js`:

```js
doStuff(1, 2);
var foo = makeFoo()
```

In Python, I know how to do this. You can hook into the import machinery and add the bindings for `doStuff` and `makeFoo` to the module's dictionary (symbol table) before you execute the code in the module file itself.

But in Javascript the only way I know to do this is add some lines to the top of every file. Something like this:

```js
import {doStuff, makeFoo} from 'builtins';
```

Is there a way to make some stuff available by default without explicit import?